# How to create a flower unfurling effect?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

The effect I am looking for is not like a simple flower but more like a plant unfurling over it's length. Like This:

[image: Flower Growing]

I am not a beginner with animation nodes but in figuring this out the greatest problem is I don't really know where and how to start.

[Here's a link to the actual video.](https://vimeo.com/232473927) -- By alex sirbu

Now to the question,
The effect is like the tip is moving forward while still unfurling.

So any help with understanding and executing this effect will be helpful.

Comment: It's interesting.. I don't get the impression the 'petals' are growing at all.. their spines are uncurling from the center, like the growth of a fern 'fiddle' frond

Comment: True but at the moment I just couldn't think of what to name it. Just changed the name.

Comment: It's Alex**A**, not Alex. She is a woman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Create a flower petal, use the object instancer node to duplicate it and connect it to a for loop.

The key concept will be the following: Connect a Time Info into *Animate Number* nodes. Use this value to drive the Rotation and the Scale to make the petals flip open and "grow".
Now all object will flip open at the same time. To make them open one after each other, qdd the instance number to the Time Info.

The rest is just getting the proper timing, spacing and interpolation.

This node setup should get you started.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just wanted to ask should using curves be able to create the curve effect. If so how to rotate the objects to the accurate angles?

Comment: @Minraws What curve effect do you mean? You can use a curve for interpolation with the animation nodes. You could also create a positional offset based on a curve with AN.

Comment: I am talking about the bezier curves and interpolation is possible but does it also give us the rotation angle?

Comment: @Minraws That's a good, but separate question. Do some research if you are still interested and post a new question if nothing comes up.